# "Overloading" a private method in PHP

Tags: php, oop, overloading

I know I cannot overload methods in PHP. And, as far as I know, `private` methods in a class are invisible to classes that extend the base class. So why this does not work?

```
class Base {
  private function foo($arg) {
     print "Base $arg";
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  public function foo() {
     print "Child";
  }
}

$c = new Child;
print $c->foo();
```

The error:

`PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of Child::foo() should be compatible with Base::foo($arg) in /var/www/boludo.php on line 17`

I assumed that `foo($arg)` method is invisible in `Child` class because is `private`. So, I'm not overloading `foo`, I'm just creating a method called `foo`.

Comment: you are calling a property, not a method

Comment: @Simon_eQ sorry, now its fixed (I was trying another code, if you look at the error Child:foo() is called :P)

Comment: They are not invisible at core level. They are unaccessible.

Comment: @DevZer0 My php --version  : `PHP 5.4.17-1~lucid+1`

Comment: @DevZer0 http://3v4l.org/mKI6O

Comment: my bad i was looking at the cli error_reporting. i get the same strict notice

Comment: The reason for the error is clearly explained in the error message.

Comment: @tereško Thx for having a look. Yes, the reason is clear. But following the rule that `private` members are just not existent in sub classes I would not have expected this. Seems that RoyalBG's comment is the answer. However, the PHP documentation could have mentioned this

Comment: @tereško Yes, but why it should be compatible? The method is private, so, according to the documentation, is invisble to the `Child` class. Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to get if some other method in `Base` calls `$this->foo()`, and that method gets called in an object of type `Child`? You have overwritten the method, but the original code has not to expect it, because the method was private.

Comment: @RoyalBg Thanks, how did you find that? I would like to read more of this topic.

Comment: @Sven You are right. Thanks for pointing towards this.

Comment: @Sven you'd expect any call to be only aware of the context it was written in. Thus methods from the base class don't know about the Child class, so they call the private function, while methods in the Child class don't know about the private function, so they'd call the public Child class function. It doesn't matter who called the function.

Comment: Interestingly, PHP >= 5.4.7 only complains if Child:foo() is public or protected. If it's private too, there's no warning even though the signatures still differ. Lower PHP versions issue a warning in all 3 cases.

Comment: @enrmarc actually I found it practically, very roughly said: you cannot hide anything from PHP. If you extend a class, the PHP core does know each method in the Base class, no matter it's private, public, protected, static, etc... And it's its job to prevent you from accessing them. So, once PHP is aware of that, at compiling time it blocks your access to the private method. It's not about visibility, it's about accessibility. If you read, for example, the C# manual for the same thing, you will never see the word "visibility": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the Notice, simply change `foo()` in the Child to

```
public function foo($arg = null) {
```

As to the question "why does this not work":

Visibility in PHP is strictly about runtime access. It doesn't affect how you can extend/compose/overload classes and methods. Loosening the visibility of a private method from a Supertype in a Subtype will add a separate method in the subtype with no access to the same named method in the supertype. However, PHP will assume a parent-child relationship for these. That didn't cause the Notice though. At least, not on it's own.

The reason why you get the Notice, is that you are then also trying to change the method signature. Your `foo()` does no longer require `$arg` to be passed to it. When you assume a parent-child relationship between the methods, this is a problem because the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) states that *"if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S"* without breaking the program. In other words: if you have code that uses `Base`, you should be able to replace `Base` with `Child` and the program should still work as if it was using `Base`.

Assume your `Base` also has a public method `bar()`.

```
class SomeClientUsingBase
{
    public function doSomethingWithBase(Base $base)
    {
        $result = $base->bar();
        // …
```

Now imagine `Child` changes `bar()` to require an argument. If you then pass `Child` for `Base` into the client, you will break the client, because the client calls `$base->bar();` without an argument.

Obviously, you could change the client to pass an argument, but then the code really depends on how `Child` defined the method, so the Typehint is wrong. In fact, `Child` is not a `Base` then, because it doesn't behave like a `Base`. It's broken inheritance then.

Now the funny thing is, if you remove that `$arg` from `foo()`, you are technically not violating LSP, because the client would still work. The Notice is wrong here. Calling `$base->foo(42)` in a client that previously used `Base` will still work with a `Child` because the `Child` can simply ignore the argument. But PHP wants you to make the argument optional then.

Note that LSP also applies to what a method may return. PHP just doesn't include the return type in the signature, so you have take that into account yourself. Your methods have to return what the Supertype returned or something that is behaviorally equivalent.

Comment: The original question was not violating LSP, since the author wanted to add a method to the public interface, not change its signature. It's a limit of the language: if a method is private, it should be completely ignored by the deriving classes. That said, I wouldn't add an ignored field to a public method just to work around this limit, changing the private method's name would be an option.

Comment: @lacopo Changing the visibility alone would have worked. But also changing the signature is what caused the Notice. And the notice is due to PHP's interpretation of LSP. It's actually two things at play here and my answer explains both. You might want to call that a bug or a limit of the language, but I think it's more helpful to the OP to explain how the language works than ramble how it should work. On a side note: deriving a child shouldn't necessitate changing the parent.

Comment: The story about LSP isn't relevant to private functions, to be honest. Actually, PHP realizes this and doesn't have the child function overwrite the parent function. However, for some reason it does require the signatures to be the same (on penalty of a strict error) which I would say is an error on PHP's part.

Comment: @Jasper I agree, but it's not irrelevant then. PHP assumes LSP here. Correctly or not, the "for some reason" is why it makes the explanation about LSP relevant.

Comment: @Gordon I'll write my own answer about the misconception this Q+A caused for me, and how it's really a misguided move by php that causes this error. I'll refer to your answer for a solution and the LSP explanation. I'll leave it up to you whether to let the two live side by side or mash the two up into one answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do function overloading in PHP using __call function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Apart from that, your problem is that in that way, you violate the Substitutability principle:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Something that PHP uses. In that way, if you replace an object of Base class type to one with a Child class type, Substitutability is violated. You are changing the interface of the base class in the derived one, removing the argument of method foo(...) and in this way, objects of Base class type can not be replaced with objects of Child class type without breaking the program, thus violating Liskov's Substitutability Principle (LSP).